# Convolution between bit stream sampled by N number of samples per bit with a channel modeled as low pass filter

Tags: adc, communication, digital-communications, transmitter, sampling

I generated a bit stream in MATLAB, from the transmitter to be convoluted by the channel

I use MATLAB function "randi" between 0 & 1, so it generates random vectors of 0s & 1s and connects them to produce triangles

I want to make N (e.g N=4) samples per bit, so each bit is produced contains 4 samples
for example    1 0 1 0 1 >>> 1111 0000 1111 0000  1111

I model channel as Low Pass Filter   e.g h = [0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4]

How can I convolute the bit stream with the channel ?

So, it should 1 1 1 1 multiplied with 0.1 and then 0000 multiplied with 0.2 and  so on

Not 1111 is multiplied with the 4 coefficients of filter channel model tabs like 1*0.1 + 1*0.2 ..etc

Is there a function in MATLAB to do this convolution with determining samples per bit ?

Comment: That's a question how to use Matlab basically. If nobody answers here for a while, you might want to re-ask this on dsp stack exchance - but not too soon as cross-posting is frowned upon. The moderators might also move this question there if they see fit.

Comment: convert to decimal then https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/610176-how-to-use-the-convolution-function-rather-than-filter-for-signal

Comment: @Justme I even want to know How will it be done, How the output will be generated serially from this filter